# JAR Selection for Creating IVY Repository

Tags: java, apache, ant, ivy

For making Repository, when i'm specifying the revision number of dependencies: i can define it by dynamic revision as:

```
[1.0,)
```

eg (in build.xml):

```
<ivy:install settingsRef="basic.settings" 
 organisation="org.springframework" 
 module="spring-beans" revision="[1.0,)"
 overwrite="TRUE"
from="${from.resolver}" to="${to.resolver}" 
transitive="TRUE"/>
```

It there a way where i can fetch ONLY the latest jar and not all from 1.0 onward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That *does* fetch only the latest jar. I ran your snippet, and it only downloaded 3.0.6 (and dependencies, of course).

Incidentally, you might find it cleaner to write:

```
revision="latest.release"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<ivy:install  organisation="org.springframework" module="spring-beans" revision="latest.integration" overwrite="TRUE" from="${from.resolver}" to="${to.resolver}" transitive="true"/>
```